# Use of undefined constant OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM - assumed 'OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM'

Tags: php, oauth

While using the upwork api library https://github.com/upwork/php-upwork, I got error
Use of undefined constant OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM - assumed 'OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM'.

I am using the OAuth1 - Authtype

here's the code I have written:

```
$config = new \Upwork\API\Config(
array('consumerKey'       => 'MY_KEY',
   'consumerSecret'    => 'MY_SECRET',
   'accessToken'       => \Session::get('access_token'),
   'accessSecret'      => \Session::get('access_secret'),
   'verifySsl'         => false,
   'debug'             => false,
   'authType'          => 'OAuth1' 
  )
);

$client = new \Upwork\API\Client($config);


if (!empty(\Session::get('access_token')) && !empty(\Session::get('access_secret'))) {
    $client->getServer()
        ->getInstance()
        ->addServerToken(
            $config::get('consumerKey'),
            'access',
            \Session::get('access_token'),
            \Session::get('access_secret'),
            0
        );
} else {
    // $accessTokenInfo has the following structure
    // array('access_token' => ..., 'access_secret' => ...);
    // keeps the access token in a secure place
    // gets info of authenticated user
    $accessTokenInfo = $client->auth();
}

$auth = new \Upwork\API\Routers\Auth($client);


print_r($auth);
```

Comment: Report an issue to the upwork, they are using an undefined constant in their code

Answer (score 0):

As per their readme:

> [You need to have] OAuth Extension installed (optional), we recommend using official pecl extension, but in case you want to use your own library, you need to drop line 'ext-oauth' from composer json, or do not use composer, which is also optional. In that case, you need to setup the 'authType' parameter in your configuration options.

And:

> IMPORTANT:
>   The library supports different OAuth clients, by default it requires PECL PHP extension

While they suggest it as optional, the `OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM` constant is [part of the PECL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/oauth.setauthtype.php).

I suggest to fix, you install the PHP OAuth extension.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, http://php.net/manual/en/oauth.setauthtype.php - it's a constant from OAuth extension. Seems you didn't install it as recommended. Otherwise, use a separate library - see details in README.